# How to generate a JWT in flutter from a key?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, jwt

I have a generate a token from a key in flutter.This token will serve as the header(authorisation) for the API call request. I am using the https://pub.dev/packages/dart_jsonwebtoken plugin to generate the token

I am able to generate the token using HS256 algorithm. But in my case I have to generate the token using RS256 algorithm.When I try to generate using RS256 algorithm it throws the following error
Instance of 'JWTInvalidError'. You can refer the screenshot as well.

The key is valid because in Java code the person was able to implement that.WHat is missing?

This is the code I have implemented using flutter dart_jsonwebtoken package:

```
import 'package:dart_jsonwebtoken/dart_jsonwebtoken.dart';

String token;

void dartJsonWebTokenGenerator() {
  Duration delay = new Duration( minutes:3);
  final jwt = JWT(
    payload:
    {
      "version": "13",
    'user_id': 'XXXXXXXXX',
    },
    issuer: 'https://github.com/jonasroussel/jsonwebtoken',
    audience: 'live-tv',
  );


// Sign it (default with HS256 algorithm)
  token = jwt.sign(PrivateKey('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'),
      algorithm: JWTAlgorithm.RS256,expiresIn: delay );

  print('Signed token: $token\n');
}
```

The equivalent Java code which is to be implemented:

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class RSAKeyGenerator {
    private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        String pKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        byte[] decode;
        decode = android.util.Base64.decode(pKey, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decode);
        return kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);
    }
    public static String getJwtToken() {
        final long VALIDITY_MS = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(60);
        long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date now = new Date(nowMillis);
        Date exp = new Date(nowMillis + VALIDITY_MS);
        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
        try {
            privateKey = getPrivateKey();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String jws = Jwts.builder()
                .claim("version", "13")
                .claim("user_id", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(exp)
                .signWith(privateKey, SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)
                .setAudience("live-tv")
                .compact();
        Log.d("111__", jws);
        SpUtil.Companion.getInstance().putString(J_TOKEN, jws);
        return jws;
    }
}
```

Along with this I have tried the jose library,corsac_jwt and a few more but I am not getting the proper results in the first place.So if you have any library you can recommend to me ,your are most welcome

[RSA 256 token error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3L3s.png)

Comment: Have you checked on jwt.io the content of your token ? Could you paste it here ?

Comment: @xurei using HS256 I could check the contents of my token in jwt.io . It is fine

Comment: Then I would guess that some required fields are missing in the payload, or that the signature is invalid. Can you check the exception and see if there is any details provided ?

Comment: It is pointing to this block of code in the jsonwebtoken library @override
  List<int> sign(Key key, List<int> body) {
    assert(key is PrivateKey, 'key must be a PrivateKey');
    final privateKey = key as PrivateKey;

    final parser = RSAPKCSParser();
    RSAKeyPair pair;

    try {
      pair = parser.parsePEM(privateKey.key, password: privateKey.passphrase);
      assert(pair.private != null);
    } catch (ex) {

      throw JWTInvalidError('invalid private RSA key');
    }

Comment: So it is basically saying invalid private key.But using the Java code it is able to generate the token

Comment: That probably means that you are not using the same key or signature algorithm in Dart vs Java. I never had to write one so I can't help you much more on this :-\

Comment: Some ideas : check the encoding (UTF-8 vs something else ?), check the keys.
Also : try to create a token with dart and validate it with dart, same thing with Java. Maybe you'll find something strange.

Comment: @xurei Thanks for all the help you could do.Ok I will